# Tkinter Checkbutton trouble

Tags: python, tkinter

im running this small python script (using tkinter) and im encountering unexpected behaviour.

```
    import Tkinter as tk

    master = tk.Tk()

    def toggleComp():
        print "toggled."

    compVar = tk.IntVar()

    check_comp = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="Specify Compostition:",variable=compVar,command=toggleComp).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=tk.W,padx=20)

    print isinstance(check_comp,tk.Checkbutton)
```

the last print line returns 'False'. 
I'd have expected 'True' as a result..

Can anyone clarify?

thanks!

Comment: Briefly: because `grid()` returns `None`. Save the object first, then grid it in a separate statement.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. But I really don't think that's the right question to link it to.

Comment: The name of the method doesn't matter. What matters is that methods operating on objects in place return `None` by convention.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: _"methods operating on objects in place return `None`"_ is not absolutely true. It depends on how the function is defined.

Comment: @BryanOakley - Well, I did say "by convention." :) And this case follows the convention, returning `None` instead of another reference to the object. So there we have it.

Comment: I just realised the problem when i ran accross it in another part of my program... thanks a lot though, guys!

Comment: I found the Tkinter-specific duplicate.