# Tkinter Checkbutton not working

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

**I know this will seem like a silly question, but I have read all the related/similar questions I could find, and I am pretty sure I am experiencing a different issue. See the end of this question for a list of similar problems which I have avoided.**

I am trying to use a Tkinter Checkbutton. I have used the example code from the documentation ([here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)) almost verbatim.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, IntVar
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.c = Checkbutton(window, 
                             text="Enable Tab",
                             variable=self.var,
                             command=self.cb)
        self.c.pack()

    def cb(self):
        print("self.var is", self.var.get())

root = Tk()
gui = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

The only thing I changed was to remove the `event` argument from the `cb` method, because as far as I could tell it wasn't being used for anything, and the checkbutton doesn't pass any `event` to `cb`.

My problem is that the variable storing the checkbutton's value always reads `0`, even when the checkbutton is checked: [image: See behaviour here]

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I know I have avoided the following pitfalls:

- [Using the wrong variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178646/tkinter-checkbutton-not-setting-variable) -- I have used Tk's `IntVar`, not a python `int`
- [Using daft colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791347/tkinter-checkbutton-stuck-unchecked)
- [Using the same attribute name for the button *and* its variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47617902/python-tkinter-checkbutton-issue) -- I have saved the button and the variable as separate attributes to my class.
- [Chaining the Checkbox creation with the place method and accidentally storing `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177007/tkinter-checkbutton-trouble)

Also, when I run code from [a question with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770471/python-tkinter-checkbutton-value-not-accesible), I get the same behaviour -- checkbox always returns False/0 -- even though that question is marked as resolved.

I am using Anaconda python with the following versions:

```
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Nov  8 2017, 14:34:30) 
[MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Comment: I get expected output in 3.2 python, Tk version 8.5

Comment: Please include your import statements. We can't tell for certain if you're using the tkinter Checkbutton or the ttk Checkbutton.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks, added the import statements to the question.

Comment: The code in that little video is not the same as the code posted in your question.  At least one difference is that this code uses `self.c` whereas the code in the video just uses `c`. I don't think that matters, but you need to make sure that the code posted is an accurate reflection of your real code.

Comment: The code in your question won't run. The import statement has a syntax error. Please provide actual code that you're running on your system. Though, even when I fix that problem, the code works fine for me.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, I updated it to `self.c` after the video (it didn't change anything)

Comment: @BryanOakley removed trailing comma from import statement (I was importing Button as well in my code, but trimmed it off for a MWE here).

Comment: @ArtemisFowl thanks for testing. I've added my python version to the question.

Comment: Your code works for me with cpython. Perhaps the problem is a bug in Anaconda.

Comment: @BryanOakley could you please tell me what tk version you have? I have 8.5.18

Comment: I've tested with 3.5.2 and 2.7.12

Comment: Thanks for your help Bryan. I've updated my tk (to v8.6.7) but still no luck.

Comment: Side note. `root.destroy()` is pointless here. Once you close the program there will not be any `root` to `destroy()`. You can delete that line.

Comment: I've tested in python 3.6.5 Tk 8.6.6, still expected result.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same problem and needs a quick fix, here's my hacky solution:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, IntVar
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.c = Checkbutton(
            window, text="Enable Tab",
            command=lambda:self.toggle(self.var))
        self.c.pack()

    def toggle(self, var):
        var.set(not var.get())

root = Tk()
gui = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove the last line. `root.destroy()`. It is pointless here and will throw an error when your program closes.

Answer (score 1):

```
chkValue = BooleanVar(root) 
chkValue.set(True)

chk = Checkbutton(root, text=' Remember Password',var=chkValue) 
chk.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=W)
```

use master

- BooleanVar(master)
- IntVar(master)
- StringVar(master)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

Maybe try to import everything from Tkinter* and delete the last line. But I think your problem is an anaconda bug.

```
from tkinter import *
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.c = Checkbutton(window, 
                             text="Enable Tab",
                             variable=self.var,
                             command=self.cb)
        self.c.pack()

    def cb(self):
        print("self.var is", self.var.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    gui = MyGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Turjak_art. Still no luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution i had to do it like this
you had the same problem calling inside and importing from a main file and using the class

```
from tkinter import Tk, Checkbutton, IntVar
class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.c = Checkbutton(window, 
                             text="Enable Tab",
                             variable=self.var,
                             command=self.cb)
        self.c.pack()

    def cb(self):
        if self.var.get() == 0:
           self.var.set(1)
        else:
           self.var.set(0)
        print("self.var is", self.var.get())

root = Tk()
gui = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```