# Tkinter checkbox can't be checked

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter

I'm on KDE-Plasma 5.18.5 Kubuntu using Python3.
The checkbox cannot be checked.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
import os

class Menu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, program, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.VERSION = tk.StringVar()#on
        self.HOST    = tk.IntVar()
        self.VERSION.set("Select Version")

        VERSION = ("1.8.x", "1.9.x")
        tk.OptionMenu(self, self.VERSION, *VERSION).place(x=200, y=125, width=185, height=100)

        tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Online server?", variable=self.HOST).place(x=200, y=400)

        tk.Button(self, text="Proceed", command=lambda: program.proceed(self.HOST, self.VERSION)).place(x=200, y=600)

class UIController:
    def __init__(self):
        self.program = Program()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.ui_menu = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.root.withdraw()

    def menu(self):
        self.ui_menu.title("mcsm")
        self.ui_menu.geometry("600x700")
        Menu(self.ui_menu, self.program).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.ui_menu.mainloop()

class Program: # To print out values from Menu.
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def proceed(self, host, version):
        print(str(host.get()) + ' ' + version.get())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    UIController().menu()
```

e.g. This:

[image: this]

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. When I copy your code into a new file and add just enough to run it, it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50276202/tkinter-checkbutton-not-working)

Comment: updated with full code

Comment: Works for me under Windows10 - Python 3.7.2 and tkinter 8.6

Comment: Works for me, too, on Windows 7 - Python 3.8.10.

Comment: update: The back and foreground colors are the same on kubuntus checkboxes. problem solved

Comment: @CXLP06 Please add an answer to your question for the future and community members.

Comment: @CXLP06 *Or* just delete your question entirely.